# Unable to import ova file - kernel driver issue Again

Tags: virtualbox

[Error screen shot](https://ibb.co/5ThFDhH)

Solution tried: 
tried to uninstall reinstall DKMS. Nothing helped.

Can some one help by seeing the screen shot?

It's a well known problem. But it seems all the solutions are not the same

[image: Cropped virtualbox error image]

Comment: what virtualbox and kernel versions?

Comment: virtual box 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

Actually disabling the secure boot did the tick to do 'modeprobe' , which again helped me in installing my VM (windows 10 ) . thanks all for suggesting edits and taking time to answer.